# the meaning of 'She knew it for a fault'

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She would presume to censure my own conduct, and press on me advice in
>   matters well beyond her understanding, and give me such words as no
>   poor man would willingly hear from his wife.’
>
> Cranmer says, ‘She was bold, it is true. **She knew it for a fault**
>   and would try to bridle herself.’
>
> *Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

What does the bold sentence mean? She knew it to be a fault?

Comment: She thought of it as a fault, not something to be very proud of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exactly the same as "She knew that it was a fault".

It's an old-fashioned, literary phrasing and you would almost never hear it in conversation today.

Comment: The only place you might hear that phrasing is in either of "Do you take me for a fool?" or "They took me for a fool.", or separately in "What do you take me for?"

Answer (score 1):

**FROM OXFORD ENGLISH DICTIONARY -**

[image]

> a. In the character of, in the light of, as equivalent to; esp. to introduce the complement after verbs of incomplete predication, e.g. *to have, hold*, etc. (see those verbs), where *as* or *as being* may generally be substituted. *to beg (a person) for a fool*.

This is the meaning OED gives. 
Now your sentence is -

> She knew it for a fault.

From the dictionary *it* is equivalent to *a fault*. Or this sentence can be rephrased as -

> She knew it to be a fault.